# Spark - reducing dataframe size & caching it

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a very large DataFrame in Spark, and it takes too long to do operations on it.

It has 10M rows.

I want to sample it so I can test things more quickly, so I am trying:

```
val redux = df.limit(1000)
redux.cache
```

I thought this would persist a dataframe with only 1K rows.

But running `redux.count` for example still takes too long (3 minutes).

I am running this on a 8 worker box w/ 6 GB RAM (from DataBricks).

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please run this `redux.count` again and watch if it's faster - should be ;) Caching is lazy, it will be done while performing first action

Comment: YES! Thanks. Other actions ran pretty fast after the first one. =D

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

Caching is performed lazily, so even though the first "count" action will take some time, subsequent operations will be faster.

Credits to T. Gaweda

Comment: It's often used in ML algorithms :) Input data is cached and then simple `count()` is calculated to perform caching. Next, when iterative part of alorithm is performed, it works on already cached data and is a lot of faster :)